# How to control only Application Brightness in iOs?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to control and set brightness only my application not the whole device.

I think there may be two ways:

1. Using `[UIScreen mainscreen]` control. But that take effect on whole device using `[UIScreen mainscreen]` I get the brightness and set into various application mode (states), But that's way also not feasible for my app because when I am doing IN/OUT (Active/Deactive) many times then actual brightness not get.
2. Using view but that's also not feasible app into many view and I want change brightness like every minutes. All view into set and get value are not perfect way. I think it's also not feasible.

So, any another ways?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I edited your question for legibility, but I think you are close with your first thought.

The [UIScreen documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) describes what you are saying: (emphasis mine)

> **brightness**
>
> The brightness level of the screen.
>
> Brightness changes made by an app remain in effect **only while the app is active**. The system restores the user-supplied brightness setting at appropriate times when your app is not in the foreground. So **if you change the value of this property, you do not need to record the previous value** and restore it when your app moves to the background.

From reading the above it looks like you just need to change the `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness` value.

Comment: The documentation seems to be wrong about that. If I change the brightness of the main screen and exit the app, the phone keeps the backlight brightness set in the app. I really do need to record the previous value and restore it. I'm using iOS 7.1 and can reproduce it with any brightness setting (no matter if auto-brightness is on or off)

Comment: How are you managing to restore the brightness just before app closes? Tried in app delegate but not working in there.